# Magento2 checkout shipping adress empty

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping-address

In checkout customer set shipping adress http://screenshots.collabstar.com/ao/252.png
But on next step in billing adress and shipping adress data is empty like on screen
http://screenshots.collabstar.com/ao/251.png 
Who has the same bropblem? I use magento2 v 2.1.7